# how to compare percentages of intervention group before and after interventions? (repeated dependent variable are presented in categorical variables)

Tags: repeated-measures, chi-squared-test, paired-data

I am conducting a randomized controlled trial, and after intervention, the numbers of patients with some characteristics (for example, prediabetes or IGT) have changed. I want to compare the percentages of some characteristics in the intervention group before and after the intervention. And, I think Pearson's chi-squared test is not appropriate because it is for comparison between two groups.

Therefore, what I can use for the comparison of percentages in single groups between different time?

Thanks for help! Any tips or suggestions will help!

Comment: If you are only interested in the before and after percentages in the intervention group, why do you have a control group?

Comment: You could look into the "Difference-in-Differences" Approach. It might be helpful in your case.

Comment: @ frank Thanks for replying. I am interested in the before and after percentages in the intervention group and percentages between the intervention group and the control group before and after percentages. I have used Pearson's chi-squared test to check the differences between the intervention group and the control group.

Comment: @ Spur Economics Thanks for helping. I will look into the "Difference-in-Differences" Approach, and hope to find appropriate statistical methods. Thanks a lot!